# Strange behavior of @RequestMapping on a maven war overlay

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I've some strange issues with @RequestMapping behavior. Here is the scenario

I have a web project with a @Controller class and some @RequestMapping methods. They work fine. One mapping is, for example, @RequestMapping("/jpm/{param}/add")

I have another web project with a war overlay on the first project. Every thing works fine, I inherite the controller and it methods. No problem so far.

Now I want a new @Controller in the 2nd project. I add it just like the other one but with a diferent @RequestMapping ("/jpm/{param}/activate") method.

@Controller and @RequestMapping are readed fine by Spring as I can see them in logs but, while  "/jpm/{param}/add" works, "/jpm/{param}/activate" does not, it says 404 resource not found.

Both classes are in different packages but both are loaded, I have two context:component-scan, one on each project. I've find that if both classes are in the same package (name), they work fine (even in diferents projects).

Is that normal? What I'm missing? Why the controller and mapping get readed but just doesn't work?

I'm getting mad with this, any advice is welcome!.

web.xml (on 1st project)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml, 
        WEB-INF/spring-locale.xml, 
        WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
        WEB-INF/spring-datasource.xml,
        WEB-INF/spring-hibernate.xml,
        WEB-INF/spring-jpm.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jpm</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
...
```

Here is my MVC config file, mostly standard stuff

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- this file will contain all of JPM Spring Web MVC-specific components -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    ...
    <context:component-scan base-package="jpaoletti.jpm2.controller"/>
    ...
</beans>
```

---

**FINAL EDIT: SOLUTION **

Just for documentation:

In 1st project, servlet config file (jpm-servlet.xml) I added

```
<import resource="jpm-servlet-custom.xml" />
```

And in 2nd project:

**jpm-servlet-custom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="another.package.controller">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

Comment: Please provide your `web.xml`.

Comment: there you go Sotirios Delimanolis

Comment: You say _Both classes are in different packages but both are loaded, I have two context:component-scan, one on each project. I've find that if both classes are in the same package (name), they work fine (even in diferents projects)_ Is the context from the second project  loaded anywhere?

Comment: Yeah, in the second project I'm overriding "spring-jpm.xml" file adding the second context:component-scan ... which make's me think that Its no being loaded in the dispathcer servlet... you may have a point here right?

Comment: Well yes, the `context:component-scan` is useless if that context is not being loaded. Import it from your `servlet-jpm.xml`.

Comment: It IS being loaded but outside DispatcherServlet. That was the problem. Following @Stephen C idea, I merged the component-scan in the jpm-servlet.xml and it worked!

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my work night xD. If you put the answer I accept it.

Comment: Seems like Stephen covers it pretty well. I did put my comments as an answer. Choose what helped more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question

> Both classes are in different packages but both are loaded, I have two
>   context:component-scan, one on each project. I've find that if both
>   classes are in the same package (name), they work fine (even in
>   diferents projects).

It seems like the second project's MVC context is either not loaded at all or not loaded by your application's `DispatcherServlet`. Because of this the `component-scan` is not loading the second project `@Controller`s.

Make sure the context is being loaded by the `DispatcherServlet.`

Comment: spring-jpm.xml doesn't have any mvc related beans. I've also a jpm-servlet file with that (which get loaded automatically by DispathcerServlet)

Comment: @jpaoletti I'll delete my answer. We'll need to see your MVC configuration then.

Comment: Edited the question with the final solution. Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 1):

> Both classes are in different packages but both are loaded, I have two context:component-scan, one on each project. I've find that if both classes are in the same package (name), they work fine (even in different projects).

I think you've probably identified the root cause of the problem here ...

---

Note that "projects" become irrelevant once you have combined everything into a single WAR file.  At execution time, classes (etc) are either visible via the classpath ... or they are not.  You may also be getting a bit confused about what the effective Spring configs are after the Maven overlaying is completed.  (Been there, done that.)  So make sure that you examine the configs in the *deployed* webapp, and base your reasoning on what is happening on *them*.

---

Based on the evidence, I think that the problems is that one of your component scans is not working / not happening.  As a result, the annotation processor is not seeing the annotations for the "missing" controller.

As an experiment, I would try "hacking" the Spring config (on the deployed webapp, in the first instance) to combine the two separate component scans into a single one that scans all relevant packages.  If that works, then figure out how to achieve the same end result using Maven overlaying.

Comment: following Sotirios Delimanolis guidance and this idea i got the solution. Thank you both very much!